# Check my drawing skills!

Tags: knowledge, visual, lateral-thinking, rebus

I was never too good at drawing, but... if this is the case, there is a word associated with this bmp image. Find out which one.[image]

Hint 1:

> What if the two living creatures change places?

Hint 2:

> I intentionally didn't draw something 3 dimensional, I didn't even try (Okay..I wouldn't be able to, either). The peculiar traits of the components are important. If you rotate the whole thing by x degrees, the placement of the components will make more sense. The knowledge tag here is (maybe unfortunately) of primary importance and unavoidable

Hint 3:

> The wavy line indeed represents water

Hint 4:

> This is the biggest giveaway so far : it's worth going back to the '80s

Hint 5:

> The word associated with image

Hint 6:

> Smiling is not relevant. The water symbol is relevant. The placement makes more sense if you rotate 180 degrees. The red color is relevant, the black is not. The peculiar shapes inside the butterfly is relevant, "bmp" is relevant, "2D image" is relevant, and both jellyfish and butterfly as "entities" are relevant. (Symbolism!)

Comment: Are you sure the answer is just one word?

Comment: Possibility of a second hint?

Comment: Hm.. OK. Even in the description there is a clue.

Comment: Ebe Isaac, yes I am sure. (And I am not the Beast, don't be afraid:)

Comment: Any update? I'm curious of the solution!

Comment: I will be the first to say that hint 2 has confused me more at the same time it has piqued my interest.

Comment: Yeeeeeah still no idea.

Comment: @FIreCase Is there any significance to some lines (e.g. antennae of butterfly and head of jellyfish) being thicker than others (e.g, butterfly wings, jellyfish tendrils)

Comment: @KEvin -yes, although not antennae and tendrils, but yes, certain attributes are encoded  in certain visible features.

Comment: @FIreCase does the word is  rot13(Ersyrpgvba)

Comment: Swati, I don't understand it, but 99% it's not, whatever you are asking.

Comment: Any chance of another hint? I really would like to know what the intended solution is.

Comment: @FIreCase - I submitted a new answer.

Comment: @Lanny, incorrect.

Comment: Just tell us, please. Nobody's getting it.

Comment: it's sprite (butterfly, water, red jellyfish,bitmap,image,2d,slot machines(slot+coin)..)

Comment: I still don't get it.

Comment: Is it really a jellyfish or head of a robot?

Comment: It's a jellyfish :))

Answer (score 9):

New Final Answer

> **LIFELINE**

Because

> Based on the latest hint - If either living animal were to cross over that squiggly line, they would no longer be living.
>  Thus, the squiggly line drawn between the creatures is a **LIFELINE**
>  How that relates to the red and the butter and jelly, I do not know.

Previous Final Answer

> **DISTORTION**

Because

> Distort - 
>  - (often passive) to twist or pull out of shape; make bent or misshapen; contort; deform
>  - to alter or misrepresent (facts, motives, etc)
>  - electronics to reproduce or amplify (a signal) inaccurately, changing the shape of the waveform
>  **The DISTORTION of the wavy water could be causing the BUTTERfly to see its reflection as a JELLYfish.**

First Answer

> **TOASTER**

Because

> First, props to @Mathgeek for finding BUTTERfly and JELLYfish
>  Both sides are situated so that the squiggly line could be the coil of a TOASTER
>  One side's piece is designated for BUTTER spreading while
>  The other side's piece is designated for JELLY spreading

Comment: Nice thoughts!! But not the intended solution. I really think this will be helpful:The word is not interchangable. Non-modifiable. That's important. That provides, namely, the uniqueness. Let's see an example:Toaster is incorrect, because toast is incorrect. I know this is not a real hint, but I consider this a useful methodological advice, that's why I wrote it here.

Comment: No, but your second answer inspired me to come up with a hint :  just twist it, if you'd like to do so!

Answer (score 8):

This likely isn't the intended solution, but it's a line of thinking we could use to solve it;

> SANDWICH

because;

> Something related to PB&J, because of the BUTTERfly and JELLYfish. Any ideas on where to actually proceed here? Could be related to fly-fishing too, but idk what the squiggly line has to do with it.

Comment: I had much the same thought. I assumed the wiggly line was the surface of the water in which the jellyfish is swimming.

Comment: I'm trying to fit the significance of the cute little smiley face being red into that construct. I can't so far.

Comment: Mathgeek: high intelligence there, since the high level of self-scepticism. Anodyne: good intentions to try things to fit, maybe nothing is by random

Comment: Could it matter that both words are composed of the same cypher-style lettering? Double-up on the 3rd letter, no other uniques, 9 letters long, could this be a cypher?

Comment: Not a cipher. (Check the tags, not random, appropriate.)

Answer (score 5):

New Answer

> **MOSES**

Because

> - We need to look at the picture as if looking down from the sky
>  - The red jellyfish (RED "C") and the water line represent the Red Sea
>  - The butterfly represents Moses looking up to God and parting the smaller version of the Red Sea in front of him with his arms spread
>  - Their path to freedom is represented by the long rectangle
>  Hints - 
>  - BMP - Bitmap - map - geographical map
>  - Looking down on a 2D map
>  - Moses was believed to be 80 when he parted the Red Sea
>  - Flipping the image 180 degrees shows the similar layout and actual direction on a map of where this exodus was headed

Previous Answer

> **JELLYFISHING**
>  This is assuming we need to focus on the only red piece in the otherwise black puzzle using hints from OP on my other answer. - Unique word - Twist it if you want
>  In a distorted world, Spongebob and Patrick go jellyfishing. Much like we would catch butterflies above the water, they catch jellyfish underwater using nets.

Comment: incorrect. twist/turn/rotate the image if you want, tell me what change you see.

Comment: @FIreCase, I figured I'd give it one last try.

Answer (score 3):

What about

> Diver

because

> Turning the image 45° you see that there are three geometrical figures resembling the letters 'D' 'I' 'O' (the heads of the animals and the body of the butterfly). DIO was a rock group of the 80's, famous for his "Holy Diver" song. So the jellyfish could be the holy diver. There is another rock song called "Holy Butterfly", that could be the butterfly. So we have the holy butterfly and the holy diver in the picture. The red face of the jerryfish make me think that he's the word we're looking for, therefore "Diver".

Comment: imaginative, but incorrect, again, based on hints, more so than on picture.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer might be:

> Die Laughing, a movie from the 1980s

Clue 1: What if the two living creatures change places?

> The jellyfish dies out of water and the butterfly drowns in the water

Clue 2: I intentionally did't draw something 3 dimensional, I didn't even try (Okay..I wouldn't be able to, either). The peculiar traits of the components are important. If you rotate the whole thing by x degrees, the placement of the components will make more sense. The knowledge tag here is (maybe unfortunately) of primary importance and unavoidable

> If you rotate the jellyfish and the butterfly, the head of the jellyfish, the line in the middle, and the wing of the butterfly will resemble the word 'die'. I *know* there is a catch here, something that relates to the knowledge part, but that was the best shot I had at explaining this

Clue 4: This is the biggest giveaway so far : it's worth going back to the '80s

> The movie, as I said, was made in the 1980s

Explaining the 'laughing' part:

> Both the creatures are smiling and  the red ink used to mark out the smile of the jellyfish probably also hints this

Comment: That's a line of thought! Unfortunately not correct. (To clear up a slight misconcept: Clues are not in the hints. Clues are in the puzzle. (All of them). Hints are aids. They could lead you to the clues.)

Answer (score 1):

My final guess is:

> 'Minecraft'

Reasoning:

> From the latest clues, it looks like you are suggesting an underwater lever (the butterfly body) and redstone (the red face), which are elements of Minecraft. Also, the reference to bmp (textures), and 2D and entities are all Minecraft references. I believe the 1980s reference is suggesting how early video games of that era resemble aspects of Minecraft.

Comment: Lanny Strack: no no, it's much more unique, has no synonyms atall. It's more like a symbolism based thing, this latter note I consider an important guide